# Enigma like python script won't return anything

Tags: python

I am trying to make a encrypter, in a similar fashion to the enigma machine but no what I try, the variable "final_message" won't print anything but blank space

```
message = input("Please input a message. ").upper()
final_message = ""
shift = 0

rotor1 = ['D','M','T','W','S','I','L','R','U','Y','O',
'N','K','F','E','J','C','A','Z','B','P','G','X','O','H','V']

for i in range(len(message)):
  if ord(message[i]) == 32:
    final_message += "n"
  else:
    num = ord(message[i]) - 65 + shift
    if num > 25:
      num -= 26
      final_message += rotor1[num]

  shift+=1

print(final_message)
```

I pretty new to coding  so I am wondering whether anyone can spot my mistake. I don't get any errors, my code just finishes without printing any letters

Answer (score 2):

It seems the indentation of `final_message += rotor1[num]` should be at the same level as that of `if num > 25`. Like this -

```
if num > 25:
    num -= 26
final_message += rotor1[num]
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer, so that it can be closed. Thanks